# Melt wide df to be long with Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm reading in a csv from disk - `print(pd.read_csv('data.csv'))`:

```
    Unnamed:0    Company1    Company2    Company3 ...
0   2019-01-01   €100,000    €100,000    €100,000
1   2019-01-02   €100,000    €100,000    €100,000
2   2019-01-03   €100,000    €100,000    €100,000
3   2019-01-04   €100,000    €100,000    €100,000
```

The CSV being read is the result of a df upstream and the unnamed date column is indexed. My problem is that I have 70+ companies and as such, 70+ columns. When I write this to a table, I want the companies to fall under a column "company_name" and then current values of "Company1", "Company2" etc to fall under a column called "predicted". I'll write then write this final df to a table with Spark.

This is my desired format:

```
date         company_name    predicted
2019-01-01   Company1        €100,000
2019-01-01   Company2        €100,000
2019-01-01   Company3        €100,000
2019-01-02   Company1        €100,000
2019-01-02   Company2        €100,000
2019-01-02   Company3        €100,000
```

I have tried this:

```
my_dict = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
df.rename(columns={'Unnamed:0': 'date'}, inplace=True)
df = df.melt(id_vars=['date'], value_vars=df.columns[1:], var_name='company_name', 
value_name='predicted')
df.sort_values(by=['date'], inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Which almost works but the date column has `NaN` values:

```
        date   company_name   predicted
0       NaN    Company1       €100,000
1       NaN    Company1       €100,000
2       NaN    Company1       €100,000
3       NaN    Company1       €100,000
4       NaN    Company1       €100,000
```

Comment: Your use case is directly analogous to the first example in the documentation for the `melt` method https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df.rename( columns={'Unnamed: 0':'yyyy_mm_dd'}, inplace=True)
df = df.melt(id_vars=['yyyy_mm_dd'])
df.rename(columns={'variable': 'company'}, inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={'value': 'predicted'}, inplace=True)

df['predicted'] = df['predicted'].str.replace('€', '')
```

Output df:

```
       yyyy_mm_dd      variable       value
0      2019-12-10      Company1       100,000
1      2019-12-11      Company1       100,000
2      2019-12-12      Company1       100,000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resort an melt like this:

```
df.rename(columns={'Unnamed:0':'date'}, inplace=True) 
df.melt(col_level=0, id_vars='date').sort_values(by='date').reset_index(drop=True)                                                                                        

          date  variable     value
0   2019-01-01  Company1  €100,000
1   2019-01-01  Company2  €100,000
2   2019-01-01  Company3  €100,000
3   2019-01-02  Company1  €100,000
4   2019-01-02  Company2  €100,000
5   2019-01-02  Company3  €100,000
6   2019-01-03  Company1  €100,000
7   2019-01-03  Company2  €100,000
8   2019-01-03  Company3  €100,000
9   2019-01-04  Company1  €100,000
10  2019-01-04  Company2  €100,000
11  2019-01-04  Company3  €100,000
```